# cannot run substrate on a fresh macbook m2

Tags: wasm, macbook, m2, apple

I have a brand new macbook m2.

I followed all the steps on https://docs.substrate.io/install/macos

```
% rustup show
Default host: aarch64-apple-darwin
rustup home:  /Users/bear/.rustup

installed toolchains
--------------------

stable-aarch64-apple-darwin (default)
nightly-aarch64-apple-darwin

active toolchain
----------------

stable-aarch64-apple-darwin (default)
rustc 1.68.0 (2c8cc3432 2023-03-06)
```

```
% rustup +nightly show
Default host: aarch64-apple-darwin
rustup home:  /Users/bear/.rustup

installed toolchains
--------------------

stable-aarch64-apple-darwin (default)
nightly-aarch64-apple-darwin

installed targets for active toolchain
--------------------------------------

aarch64-apple-darwin
wasm32-unknown-unknown

active toolchain
----------------

nightly-aarch64-apple-darwin (overridden by +toolchain on the command line)
rustc 1.70.0-nightly (4a04d086c 2023-03-18)
```

While trying to run substrate, I run into:

```
% ./target/release/substrate --dev
2023-03-19 22:51:50 Substrate Node    
2023-03-19 22:51:50 ✌️  version 3.0.0-dev-f8a1dd4c836    
2023-03-19 22:51:50 ❤️  by Parity Technologies <admin@parity.io>, 2017-2023    
2023-03-19 22:51:50  Chain specification: Development    
2023-03-19 22:51:50   Node name: dramatic-road-4106    
2023-03-19 22:51:50  Role: AUTHORITY    
2023-03-19 22:51:50  Database: RocksDb at /var/folders/0n/4nqy69197mdfz6tz2sbrpwcm0000gn/T/substrateYXoVQu/chains/dev/db/full    
2023-03-19 22:51:50 ⛓  Native runtime: node-268 (substrate-node-0.tx2.au10)    
Error: Service(Client(VersionInvalid("cannot deserialize module: UnknownOpcode(192)")))
2023-03-19 22:51:51 [0]  generated 1 npos voters, 1 from validators and 0 nominators    
2023-03-19 22:51:51 [0]  generated 1 npos targets    
2023-03-19 22:51:51 Cannot create a runtime error=Other("cannot deserialize module: UnknownOpcode(192)")
```

which is coming from [`client/executor/common/src/runtime_blob/runtime_blob.rs`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/f8a1dd4c836d7d29382ba66fc2fce40fc1364546/client/executor/common/src/runtime_blob/runtime_blob.rs#L51)

The same happens with a few other repositories, namely:

- `substrate-node-template`
- `frontier-node-template`

but it **does not** happen with `polkadot`.

Comment: I tried everything explained here in the above comments but having same error. My machine configuration is: MacBook Pro
2.3 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i5
macOS ventura 13.1 any other step?

Comment: Same issues here with rust version 1.68.2 on ubuntu 22.04 linux.

Comment: I also had issue on my new `M1 MacBook Pro Ventura 13.3`. Previously I had `stable-1.68.2` and `nightly-1.70`. I had to fallback into `nightly-1.68` Created `rust-toolchain.toml` with ```toml
[toolchain]
channel = "nightly-2023-01-01"
components = [ "rustfmt" ]
targets = [ "wasm32-unknown-unknown" ]
profile = "minimal"
``` Thanks to the community for help. Here is the error message I was getting: ```sh
./target/release/node-template --dev
Error: Service(Client(VersionInvalid("cannot deserialize module: UnknownOpcode(192)")))
2023-04-05 16:10:40 Substrate Node
2023-04-05 16:10:40 ✌️ version 4.0

Answer (score 12, accepted):

solved by downgrading nightly from `1.70` to `1.68`

interestingly, I couldn't really downgrade by simply calling `rustup` commands

I had to do `rustup install nightly-2023-01-01` to make `1.68`available, then I had to rename `~/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-2023-01-01-aarch64-apple-darwin` to `~/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-aarch64-apple-darwin`. This was the only way I could successfully downgrade nightly.

Comment: Use `rustup default` to set your default toolchain. I think your default toolchain is `nightly`.

Comment: i use `rustup override`

Comment: i followed the official substrate installation instructions i was able to solve the issue on substrate-node-template repo by running `rustup override set nightly-2023-01-01 && rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown`. view the override with `rustup toolchain list`. if you want to remove the override and revert back to defaults just run `rustup override unset`.

Comment: that renaming was a ninja move, and worked for me

Answer (score 8):

I had the same error, and solved it by adding a rust-toolchain.toml file in my project root folder to override the toolchain.
The content of rust-toolchain.toml is:

```
[toolchain]
channel = "nightly-2023-01-01"
components = [ "rustfmt" ]
targets = [ "wasm32-unknown-unknown" ]
profile = "minimal"
```

Comment: i upvoted this before trying it. but this didn't work for me. it just returned error `error[E0786]: found invalid metadata files for crate sp_std` and `error: cannot determine resolution for the derive macro sp_std::hash::Hash`

Answer (score 3):

There are a bunch of ways to override your nightly toolchain, see https://rust-lang.github.io/rustup/overrides.html for further information.

Answer (score 3):

after downgrading to nightly 1.68, and you need to cargo build --package node-template --release again.

Comment: i tried this but doesn't work. i used latest substrate repo master commit 35049b176e49ca23240d1ee3ec6c190804e3b4d1, followed the official substrate installation instructions but when i ran `cargo build --package node-template --release` it gave error `error: unknown --json` option future-incompat` and `error: could not compile ff (lib)`, then i downgraded to 1.68 nightly `rustup override set nightly-2023-01-01 && rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown` and ran `cargo build --package node-template --release` again but gave error `found invalid metadata files for crate proc_macro2`

Comment: if i use latest substrate repo master commit 35049b176e49ca23240d1ee3ec6c190804e3b4d1, follow official substrate install instructions and build with just `cargo build --release` it compiles successfully and i can run node without error. but if i use latest substrate-node-template repo master commit 700c3a186e55d0d6542c564ccff17260238ed752, follow official substrate installation instructions, then it gives error `cannot deserialize module: UnknownOpcode(192)` unless i run `rustup override set nightly-2023-01-01 && rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown` before running `cargo build --release`

Comment: Luke i run this `rustup override set nightly-2023-01-01 && rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown` but it in rustup +nightly show i get:

...
nightly-2023-01-01-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
1.68-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
1.68.2-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)

installed targets for active toolchain
--------------------------------------

wasm32-unknown-unknown
x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

active toolchain
----------------

nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (overridden by +toolchain on the command line)
rustc 1.72.0-nightly (e6d4725c7 2023-06-05)

Comment: as it doesnt seem to be changing the night to 1.68, it still says 1.72...

Comment: actually i followed Bernado's renaming procedure, and it now shows the correct version.

Answer (score 3):

The `WASM_BUILD_TOOLCHAIN` env variable should be able to override the nightly that is used for the WASM build. So if you set that to something older it should work.

Comment: i upvoted this before trying it, but after trying it with `WASM_BUILD_TOOLCHAIN=nightly-2023-01-01 cargo build --release` in the subtrate-node-template repo i found it doesn't work. it just gives the `Rust WASM toolchain not installed, please install it!` error, and even if you then follow its suggestion and install it with `rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown` and then build again it just shows the same error.

Comment: Yea the recommendation is not really correct. AFAIK it should be `rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown --toolchain nightly`, or whatever exact nightly you are using.