# Substrate Node Template does not start

Tags: substrate-node-template

I followed the tutorial on https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-a-blockchain/build-local-blockchain/ exactly, but after building the node template (https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template) and trying to run it with `./target/release/node-template --dev` I get the following error message:

```
Error: Service(Client(VersionInvalid("cannot deserialize module: UnknownOpcode(192)")))
2023-04-04 21:13:57 Substrate Node    
2023-04-04 21:13:57 ✌️  version 4.0.0-dev-700c3a186e5    
2023-04-04 21:13:57 ❤️  by Substrate DevHub <https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub>, 2017-2023    
2023-04-04 21:13:57  Chain specification: Development    
2023-04-04 21:13:57   Node name: future-carriage-5924    
2023-04-04 21:13:57  Role: AUTHORITY    
2023-04-04 21:13:57  Database: RocksDb at /tmp/substrate7hcjlL/chains/dev/db/full    
2023-04-04 21:13:57 ⛓  Native runtime: node-template-100 (node-template-1.tx1.au1)    
2023-04-04 21:13:57 Cannot create a runtime error=Other("cannot deserialize module: UnknownOpcode(192)")
```

Answer (score 3):

This issue happens in recent rust nightly builds, try downgrading to `nightly-2023-03-14`

More info:

- https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/13636
- [cannot run substrate on a fresh macbook m2](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/7714/cannot-run-substrate-on-a-fresh-macbook-m2)

Once you downgrade the nightly toolchain, you will have to build the project again.