# Getting error for running the substrate-contracts-node

Tags: substrate-contracts-node

first I installed the substrate contract node from this command `cargo install contracts-node --git https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node.git` from [paritytech GitHub](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node/blob/72e68577688cd1764da6730521c6f06f7e530a5e/README.md?plain=1#L54)

I got too many errors while installing and errors were related to `use std::sync:OnceLock`

then installed the substrate contract node from [ink docs](https://use.ink/getting-started/setup#2-build-it-yourself)
`cargo install contracts-node --git https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node.git --tag v0.23.0 --force --locked`.

I got warnings while installing `` warning: Could not find `Cargo.lock` for `/Users/xyz/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-contracts-node-cf7c16677784d274/87a3d76/runtime/Cargo.toml`, while searching from `/var/folders/5k/5_v4gg194h1dh04gp2hg3qbm0000gn/T/cargo-installMIxejX/release/build/contracts-node-runtime-cad7bb71042b6508/out`. To fix this, point the `WASM_BUILD_WORKSPACE_HINT` env variable to the directory of the workspace being compiled. ``

````
   Replacing /Users/xyz/.cargo/bin/substrate-contracts-node
    Replaced package `contracts-node v0.23.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node.git?tag=v0.23.0#87a3d76c)` with `contracts-node v0.23.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node.git?tag=v0.23.0#87a3d76c)` (executable `substrate-contracts-node`) 

then I ran ```substrate-contracts-node``` on my terminal, getting ```Error: Service(Client(VersionInvalid("cannot deserialize module: UnknownOpcode(192)")))```

INFO main sc_cli::runner: Substrate Contracts Node    
2023-08-15 13:49:37.552  INFO main sc_cli::runner: ✌️  version 0.23.0-87a3d76c880    
2023-08-15 13:49:37.552  INFO main sc_cli::runner: ❤️  by Parity Technologies <admin@parity.io>, 2021-2023    
2023-08-15 13:49:37.552  INFO main sc_cli::runner:  Chain specification: Development    
2023-08-15 13:49:37.552  INFO main sc_cli::runner:   Node name: extra-small-art-3879    
2023-08-15 13:49:37.552  INFO main sc_cli::runner:  Role: AUTHORITY    
2023-08-15 13:49:37.552  INFO main sc_cli::runner:  Database: ParityDb at /var/folders/5k/5_v4gg194h1dh04gp2hg3qbm0000gn/T/substrate1tebHT/chains/dev/paritydb/full    
2023-08-15 13:49:37.552  INFO main sc_cli::runner: ⛓  Native runtime: substrate-contracts-node-100 (substrate-contracts-node-1.tx1.au1)    
Error: Service(Client(VersionInvalid("cannot deserialize module: UnknownOpcode(192)")))
2023-08-15 13:49:37.610  WARN main wasm-runtime: Cannot create a runtime error=Other("cannot deserialize module: UnknownOpcode(192)")
````

Answer (score 2):

Regarding `cannot deserialize module: UnknownOpcode(192)`. This kind of error is related to the toolchain usually, check [Substrate-Node-Template does not start after cloning and renaming the template UnknownOpcode(192)](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/7992/substrate-node-template-does-not-start-after-cloning-and-renaming-the-template-u).

Regarding `errors were related to use std::sync:OnceLock`. In case it's something like that.

```
error[E0658]: use of unstable library feature 'once_cell'
   --> /home/user/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate/client/executor/wasmtime/src/util.rs:147:6
    |
147 |     use std::sync::OnceLock;
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

That means it wants you to build it with unstable features support which are enabled for nightly toolchain releases. Make sure you went through `https://docs.substrate.io/install/` to setup the right Rust toolchain. You may also to force cargo to use a nightly toolchain passing `+nightly` to cargo like that.

```
cargo install contracts-node --git https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node.git
```

More about unstable features: https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/unstable.html.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding

> then installed the substrate contract node from ink docs
> `cargo install contracts-node --git https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node.git --tag v0.23.0 --force --locked`

this ink doc is outdated, as per https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/10442/2540

you will find solution there which worked for me