# substrate contracts node compilation failed

Tags: substrate-contracts-node

Following

https://use.ink/getting-started/setup#2-build-it-yourself

```
cargo install contracts-node --git https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node.git --tag v0.23.0 --force --locked
```

gives following errors

```
warning: Could not find `Cargo.lock` for `/home/jan/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-contracts-node-cf7c16677784d274/87a3d76/runtime/Cargo.toml`, while searching from `/tmp/cargo-install7jKdKe/release/build/contracts-node-runtime-143506e184989dd7/out`. To fix this, point the `WASM_BUILD_WORKSPACE_HINT` env variable to the directory of the workspace being compiled.
warning: Could not find `Cargo.lock` for `/home/jan/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-contracts-node-cf7c16677784d274/87a3d76/runtime/Cargo.toml`, while searching from `/tmp/cargo-install7jKdKe/release/build/contracts-node-runtime-143506e184989dd7/out`. To fix this, point the `WASM_BUILD_WORKSPACE_HINT` env variable to the directory of the workspace being compiled.

error: failed to run custom build command for `contracts-node-runtime v0.23.0 (/home/jan/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-contracts-node-cf7c16677784d274/87a3d76/runtime)`
Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/tmp/cargo-install7jKdKe/release/build/contracts-node-runtime-9fdb9c9faf907e21/build-script-build` (exit status: 1)
  --- stdout
  cargo:warning=Could not find `Cargo.lock` for `/home/jan/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-contracts-node-cf7c16677784d274/87a3d76/runtime/Cargo.toml`, while searching from `/tmp/cargo-install7jKdKe/release/build/contracts-node-runtime-143506e184989dd7/out`. To fix this, point the `WASM_BUILD_WORKSPACE_HINT` env variable to the directory of the workspace being compiled.
  cargo:warning=Could not find `Cargo.lock` for `/home/jan/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-contracts-node-cf7c16677784d274/87a3d76/runtime/Cargo.toml`, while searching from `/tmp/cargo-install7jKdKe/release/build/contracts-node-runtime-143506e184989dd7/out`. To fix this, point the `WASM_BUILD_WORKSPACE_HINT` env variable to the directory of the workspace being compiled.
  Information that should be included in a bug report.
  Executing build command: RUSTFLAGS="-C link-arg=--export-table -Clink-arg=--export=__heap_base -C link-arg=--import-memory  " SKIP_WASM_BUILD="" "rustup" "run" "nightly" "cargo" "rustc" "--target=wasm32-unknown-unknown" "--manifest-path=/tmp/cargo-install7jKdKe/release/wbuild/contracts-node-runtime/Cargo.toml" "--color=always" "--profile" "release"
  Using rustc version: rustc 1.73.0 (cc66ad468 2023-10-03)
  --- stderr
...
     Compiling wasmi_core v0.5.0
  error[E0554]: `#![feature]` may not be used on the stable release channel
    --> /home/jan/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/1cc97dd/primitives/io/src/lib.rs:22:35
     |
  22 | #![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), feature(alloc_error_handler))]
     |                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

     Compiling tempfile v3.8.1
  For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0554`.
  error: could not compile `sp-io` (lib) due to previous error
  warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: failed to compile `contracts-node v0.23.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node.git?tag=v0.23.0#87a3d76c)`, intermediate artifacts can be found at `/tmp/cargo-install7jKdKe`.
```

how to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version used in the documentation is a bit old, you can try with the latest following the steps in the [README of the project](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node/blob/main/README.md):

```
git clone https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node.git
```

Install contracts node:

```
cargo install contracts-node
```

And run it:

```
substrate-contracts-node
```