# Zombienet error running polkadot v0.9.37

Tags: polkadot, zombienet

I'm using zombienet 1.3.43 and I built the Polkadot binary locally. I'm using macbook pro M1.

config.toml:

```
[settings]
timeout = 1000

[relaychain]
default_command = "./bin/polkadot"
default_args = [ "-lparachain=debug" ]
chain = "rococo-local"

  [[relaychain.nodes]]
  name = "alice"
  ws_port = 9900
  validator = true
```

I get this error:

[image]

I have tested with previous versions of zombienet, the process finishes without any error in console:[image]

Error in log:

```
2023-04-20 11:19:19.442  INFO main sc_cli::runner: Parity Polkadot    
2023-04-20 11:19:19.443  INFO main sc_cli::runner: ✌️  version 0.9.37-645723987cf    
2023-04-20 11:19:19.443  INFO main sc_cli::runner: ❤️  by Parity Technologies <admin@parity.io>, 2017-2023    
2023-04-20 11:19:19.443  INFO main sc_cli::runner:  Chain specification: Rococo Local Testnet    
2023-04-20 11:19:19.443  INFO main sc_cli::runner:   Node name: alice    
2023-04-20 11:19:19.443  INFO main sc_cli::runner:  Role: AUTHORITY    
2023-04-20 11:19:19.443  INFO main sc_cli::runner:  Database: RocksDb at /var/folders/lc/2st7lfb94fl0_1mp5jl2s8c80000gq/T/zombie-0a02cef3367fa8a9f482d4d088ce1a17_-34666-EbTf4ChDfnO1/alice/data/chains/rococo_local_testnet/db/full    
2023-04-20 11:19:19.443  INFO main sc_cli::runner: ⛓  Native runtime: rococo-9370 (parity-rococo-v2.0-0.tx18.au0)    
Error: 
   0: [91mFailed to get runtime version: cannot deserialize module: UnknownOpcode(192)[0m

Backtrace omitted. Run with RUST_BACKTRACE=1 environment variable to display it.
Run with RUST_BACKTRACE=full to include source snippets.
2023-04-20 11:19:20.512  WARN main wasm-runtime: Cannot create a runtime error=Other("cannot deserialize module: UnknownOpcode(192)")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is not with Zombienet, is with your binary.

You have to downgrade to `nightly 1.68` and build your binary again. See this previous StackExchange discussions where this was fixed: [Cannot run substrate on a fresh macbook m2](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/7714/cannot-run-substrate-on-a-fresh-macbook-m2)

Comment: It worked, thank you.