# (Parachain) cannot create a runtime error=Other("cannot deserialize module: unknown Opcode(192)")

Tags: parachain, substrate-parachain-template, relay-chain

I was following the substrate SDK official documentation for building a parachain on the Polkadot blockchain, and in the connect a local parachain tutorial(https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-a-parachain/connect-a-local-parachain/), the collator node is not starting and giving the following error:

[image]

I added the rust-toolchain.toml file in the substrate-parachain-template as given in the following link [cannot run substrate on a fresh macbook m2](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/7714/cannot-run-substrate-on-a-fresh-macbook-m2) and compiled it again but it is still giving the same error please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cannot run substrate on a fresh macbook m2](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/7714/cannot-run-substrate-on-a-fresh-macbook-m2)

Comment: No tried it still giving the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kindly downgrade your nightly version you can downgrade it to 68.

Comment: can u elaborate exactly how i do it for (https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-a-parachain/connect-a-local-parachain/), adding rust-toolchain.toml file and re compiling worked for substrate-node-template but not for substrate-parachain-template

Comment: It worked I added the rust-toolchain.toml file in the relay chain branch as well the version of nightly were different in para chain and relay chain