# wasm compilation for later rust versions

Tags: runtime, wasm, nodes

I am running a parachain on Ubuntu 22.04 jammy. where i am using polkadot 9.43. I see that in release notes it is said that nightly-2023-05-22 was tested for this substrate version https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/releases/tag/v0.9.43. I also see that substrate is using rust 1.70 https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/commit/68fe1efa5c033240e394d7a1e7e85f86ef371fe8. However if i try to use any rust nightly version past 2023-03-09, when i am running a node for my runtime i get error:
(Parachain) cannot create a runtime error=Other("cannot deserialize module: unknown Opcode(192)")

solutions i find online [here](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/7714/cannot-run-substrate-on-a-fresh-macbook-m2) and [here](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/8500/parachain-cannot-create-a-runtime-error-othercannot-deserialize-module-unkn) suggest to downgrade to rust 1.68. Could you please tell me if there is another option to fix this issue?  will this issue be fixed for later versions of rust to be able to build wasm files for later substrate versions?

Thank you very much for your help!