# How do i verify i have the correct version of substrate binaries and libraries as required by substrate-parachain-template?

Tags: substrate-parachain-template

How do I verify I have the correct version of substrate binaries and libraries as required by substrate-parachain-template, and How do I write a rust-toolchain.toml file that matches the versions required by substrate node template?

Comment: you can check it in the runtime cargo.toml file  https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-parachain-template/blob/main/runtime/Cargo.toml can you give some more detail what exactly you want to ask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly add more clarity to your question.try to add some screenshots and to give more details about it.

Comment: I am getting (Parachain) cannot create a runtime error=Other("cannot deserialize module: unknown Opcode(192)") error while trying to start the collator node and connect to relay chain so wanted to check the version compatibility between parachain and relay chain

Comment: which version you are using?

Comment: Some versions of substrate are having this issue with certain rust versions, I believe that the latest one fixed it. I would recommend you to use this https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/7890/4081