# Enable to build substrate node template on M2

Tags: substrate-node-template

The following error msg is given out

```
error: failed to run custom build command for `tikv-jemalloc-sys v0.5.3+5.3.0-patched`
```

Clang version

```
Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin22.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

GCC version

```
Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin22.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

rustup show

```
Default host: aarch64-apple-darwin
rustup home:  /Users/nakul/.rustup

installed toolchains
--------------------

stable-aarch64-apple-darwin (default)
nightly-2022-12-15-aarch64-apple-darwin
nightly-2023-01-01-aarch64-apple-darwin
nightly-2023-02-21-aarch64-apple-darwin
nightly-aarch64-apple-darwin

installed targets for active toolchain
--------------------------------------

aarch64-apple-darwin
wasm32-unknown-unknown
x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

active toolchain
----------------

nightly-2022-12-15-aarch64-apple-darwin 
rustc 1.68.0-nightly (b70baa4f9 2022-12-14)
```

Comment: May be relevant: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/7714/cannot-run-substrate-on-a-fresh-macbook-m2

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick to 1.68, I just tried compiling [substrate-node-template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template) and it worked fine, only difference is the monthly.

Here is my `rustup show`:

```
Default host: aarch64-apple-darwin
rustup home:  /Users/bruno/.rustup

installed toolchains
--------------------

stable-aarch64-apple-darwin (default)
nightly-2023-01-01-aarch64-apple-darwin
nightly-2023-01-30-aarch64-apple-darwin
nightly-aarch64-apple-darwin
1.68.0-aarch64-apple-darwin

installed targets for active toolchain
--------------------------------------

aarch64-apple-darwin
wasm32-unknown-unknown

active toolchain
----------------

nightly-2023-01-01-aarch64-apple-darwin (directory override for '/Users/bruno/src')
rustc 1.68.0-nightly (574b64a97 2022-12-31)
```

You can try switching by creating a `rust-toolchain.toml` file in your project's root directory:

```
[toolchain]
channel = "nightly-2023-01-01"
components = [ "rustfmt" ]
targets = [ "wasm32-unknown-unknown" ]
profile = "minimal"
```

OR by using the `rustup override set nightly-2023-01-01` command inside your project directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install following libraries:

1. `apt get install make` and/or
2. `cargo install fd-find`

Also try to use both versions of toolchains:

1. `rustup default stable`
2. `rustup default nightly`

[More information](https://github.com/gnzlbg/jemallocator/issues/148)