# Substate node not compiling on Archlinux

Tags: substrate-node-template, runtime, polkadot-local

Recently anytime i try to run `substrate-node` i get this error message, all attempts to update packages hasn't been helpful

```
Error: Service(Client(VersionInvalid("cannot deserialize module: UnknownOpcode(192)")))
2023-06-22 02:56:29.665  WARN main wasm-runtime: Cannot create a runtime error=Other("cannot deserialize module: UnknownOpcode(192)")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a substrate issue with latest rust (after 1.69) and releases before `polkadot-v0.9.39`. You should use `nightly-2023-01-01` or rustc at 1.68 or earlier to compile:

```shell
cargo +nightly-2023-01-01 build --release
```

---

More info here : [cannot run substrate on a fresh macbook m2](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/7714/cannot-run-substrate-on-a-fresh-macbook-m2)

Comment: I have tried the option of using an earlier nightly version but the issue still persists

Comment: Please anyone who can help me on this, I have been stuck for days and tried every suggestion i could fine but none is working 
```
error: failed to run custom build command for `wasm-opt-sys v0.111.0`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully:```

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out after trying all the options, running this helps rebuild the dependencies for rocksdb
`pacman -U https://archive.archlinux.org/packages/g/gcc/gcc-12.2.1-4-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst https://archive.archlinux.org/packages/g/gcc-libs/gcc-libs-12.2.1-4-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst`

Comment: Hmmm. I don’t think so. I’ve a lot of arch linux machines. No one can reproduce this. (I always keeping everything up to date)